# Oracle UCP Incorrect JMX Support

Tags: jmx, ucp

I tried out the jmx support for the universal connection pool and it seems to give incorrect values.
There are couple of problems I have faced till now

1. The getConnectionPoolNames() method (operation) of the UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean returns void instead of returning a Collection.
2. The getStatistics() method (operation) of the UniversalConnectionPoolMBean throws an NotSerializableException.

Though there are workarounds to the above problems like calling other methods instead of the above ones the issues seem to be very basic. 
Has anyone tried out the JMX support provided by the Universal Connection Pool (ucp)?